# How to deploy a WAR file from s3 to AWS EC2?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS EC2 instance running with me and there is a maven project running on tomcat7. What I have tried is I am using Jenkins for the CI.So whenever the new push happens to the Git-hub Jenkins starts to build, after completion of build it will upload the war file to the AWS S3.
Where I have stuck is, I am not getting a way to deploy the war file to the AWS Ec2 instance.

I have tried to use Code Deployment where at a point it showed me that it supports only tar, tar.gz and zip is there any way out to deploy the war file to the AWS EC2 instance from the S3.

Thank you.

Comment: what about running a script on aws ec2 instance to pull war from s3?

Comment: I need it to be done automatically. like when jenkins upload a war file for example code deploy gets the it and deploy it to the ec2 instance

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Amazon Code Deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) which can manage deployment from a S3 bucket and can automate deployment to EC2 instance of your file/scripts.

From the [Overview of a Deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html#welcome-deployment-overview)

> Here's how it works:
>
> 1. First, you create deployable content – such as web pages, executable
>    files, setup scripts, and so on – on your local development machine or
>    similar environment, and then you add an application specification
>    file (AppSpec file). The AppSpec file is unique to AWS CodeDeploy; it
>    defines the deployment actions you want AWS CodeDeploy to execute. You
>    bundle your deployable content and the AppSpec file into an archive
>    file, and then upload it to an Amazon S3 bucket or a GitHub
>    repository. This archive file is called an application revision (or
>    simply a revision).
> 2. Next, you provide AWS CodeDeploy with
>    information about your deployment, such as which Amazon S3 bucket or
>    GitHub repository to pull the revision from and which set of instances
>    to deploy its contents to. AWS CodeDeploy calls a set of instances a
>    deployment group. A deployment group contains individually tagged
>    instances, Amazon EC2 instances in Auto Scaling groups, or both.
>    Each time you successfully upload a new application revision that you
>    want to deploy to the deployment group, that bundle is set as the
>    target revision for the deployment group. In other words, the
>    application revision that is currently targeted for deployment is the
>    target revision. This is also the revision that will be pulled for
>    automatic deployments.
> 3. Next, the AWS CodeDeploy agent on each
>    instance polls AWS CodeDeploy to determine what and when to pull the
>    revision from the specified Amazon S3 bucket or GitHub repository.
> 4. Finally, the AWS CodeDeploy agent on each instance pulls the target
>    revision from the specified Amazon S3 bucket or GitHub repository and,
>    using the instructions in the AppSpec file, deploys the contents to
>    the instance.
>
> AWS CodeDeploy keeps a record of your deployments so
> that you can get information such as deployment status, deployment
> configuration parameters, instance health, and so on.

Good part is that code deploy has no additional cost, you only pay for the resources (EC2, S3) that are used in your pipeline

Comment: Hey @Frédéric thank you for sharing your knowledge. I am stucked with WAR files the jenkins is uploading a war file and Code Deploy doesnt support WAR file to deploy, is there any other way out? other question where should we put our APpspec.yml file?

Comment: Hey @BhavikJoshi you can zip your war and tell when you run `aws deploy ... --s3-location bucket=<yourbucket>,key=<yourfile>,bundleType=zip` the appspec.yml file will go on your EC2 instance where you will call the `aws deploy` from

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already created a S3 bucket.

**Step 1:** Create a IAM user / Role who have access to a s3 bucket where in you are placing the WAR file

**Step 2:** Write a custom script which will download WAR File from S3 to your EC2 instance.

You can also use aws cli to download contents from s3 to your local machine.

Create a **startup.sh** file and add these contents

```
aws s3 cp s3://com.yoursitename/warFile/sample.war /tmp
sudo mv /tmp/sample.war /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
sudo service tomcat restart
```

Comment: Thanks @vikash but I want automation where  when the file is being uploaded to the s3 it should be deployed to the EC2 instance.

Comment: You need to use some CI/CD tools for that.. You can go with Jenkins

Comment: @BhavikJoshi: create a service, which triggers change on s3.